# How can I add a services directory to the load path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails project, I want to add `services` directory in `app` folder and include some service objects.

So let's say I want to add `app/services/foo/test.rb` which looks like:

```
module Services
  module Foo
    class Test

    end
  end
end
```

In my `config/application.rb` I added:

```
config.paths.add File.join('app', 'services'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '*')]
```

However when I try to load the files in console it doesn't work:

```
⇒  rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
[1] pry(main)> Services::Foo::Test
NameError: uninitialized constant Services
```

Any help how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try reloading your rails console?

Comment: @KumarAbinash yes I did and still not working :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, the code under `app` folder will be loaded without any config.

I think the problem was the folder structure doesn't match with your class definition.

So this config will work:

**app/services/foo/test.rb**

```
module Foo
  class Test
  end
end
```

My clue is, for example we have `app/controllers/api/v1/users_controllers.rb` and the class constant will be `Api::V1::UsersController`, not `Controllers::Api::V1::UsersController`

**Update**

Conventionally, we usually use `FooServices` instead of `Foo`, it is clearer, for example:

**app/services/foo_services/bar_parser.rb**

```
module FooServices
  class BarParser
    # Do stuff
  end
end
```

So we understand that every class inside `foo_services` folder is a service which related to `Foo`

Comment: This is a good point, however this wont solve my problem. The thing is that I want to specify that `Foo` is related to Services and *NOT* any Foo. Imagine we are talking about common class like `User`. I want to say that I'm interested of `Service::User` but not `User` the model. Is there anyway of doing that?

Comment: Thanks, with "proper file path" and "class defination" it work now (I am using Rails 5.2). it **Doesn't work** if I just simply write  `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services')]` OR `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'services')` OR comment out `#config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` OR`config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker`.

Answer (score 39):

After add new dir, reload spring
`spring stop`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was because of Rails naming conventions, I suppose. I just renamed class to not use `module Services` and it worked.